# Non-italicization of Greek capitals

Tags: soft-question, notation

In typesetting mathematics, why are capitals Greek letters not italicized (e.g. $\Gamma$) unlike lower case Greek letters (e.g. $\gamma$) or capital Roman letters (e.g. $G$)?

Comment: Lower case Greek letters are only written one way, there is no "Italic/Roman" dichotomy in writing them.

Comment: My understanding is that lower case Greek letters were, historically, just sloppy handwritten versions of upper case, which eventually became crystallized into standard shapes by typographers.

Comment: @LeeMosher: are you so sure ? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Modern_Greek_alphabet_sample.svg

Comment: Relevant answer on TeX.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119262/94091

Comment: Those look terrible! @YvesDaoust :-)

Comment: But the way, the [unaccepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119261/95520) on the link provided by @Chappers gives some details consistent with my comment.

Comment: I think the real question is why do we italicise the latin lettered functions. We specifically *don't* when the function has multiple letters (e.g., $\sin x$ instead of $sin\ x$) to emphasise that the function isn't a constant.

Comment: [This tex.stackexchange Q](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163101/) suggests that the divide is historical and that even printing presses had un-italicised Greek upper case vs. italicised Greek lower case.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Very useful and interesting comments.